# React Native Camera Image with Text

Tags: react-native, camera

I want to do image capture and pass text along with the image in react native app, just like whatsapp does. When you invoke the camera to take a picture it will just capture the image and there is no way to add the text. Is there any component available for this kind of requirement.

Something like this [Sample Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6yb0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No component can achieve that at the moment, you can simply add text on the picture juste like: https://medium.com/@mheavers/vertically-centering-text-over-images-in-react-native-with-flexbox-935e822751f3

and use this package to save it as an image

https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera).